# error while passing values in push operation in stack implementation(Parenthesis matching)

Tags: c++, data-structures, error-handling, parentheses

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Stack{
public:
  int top;
  int size;
  string *s;

  void isBalanced(Stack *st,string exp);
};
```

push function is

```
void push(Stack *st,string x){
if(st->top==st->size-1)
    cout<<"Stack full\n";

    else{

        st->top++;
        st->s[st->top]=x;
    }
}
```

pop function

```
string pop(Stack *st){

string x;
if(st->top==-1)
    cout<<"Stack is empty\n";
    else{

        x=st->s[st->top--];
    }
    return x;
}
```

errored function

```
void Stack::isBalanced(Stack *st,string exp){

for(int i=0;exp[i]!='\0';i++){
    if(exp[i]=='('){
       push(st,exp[i]);

       }else if(exp[i]==')'){

        if(top==-1)
            cout<<"stack empty\n";

        pop(st);

       }

}

if(top==-1)
    cout<<"Balanced\n";
else
    cout<<"Not balanced\n";

}
```

in main

```
int main()
{

Stack st;

string expression;
cout<<"ENTER EXPRESSION TO CHECK PARENTHESIS BALANCED OR NOT : ";
cin>>expression;

st.size=expression.length();
st.top=-1;
st.s=new string[st.size];


st.isBalanced(&st,expression);


}
```

here i was trying to implement parenthesis matching problem using in c++ but in the line below code throws error in function isBalanced please
try
to fix
my problem

```
push(st,exp[i]);
```

this line throws error canot covert something... and i cant able to fix it.I had donr all posible ways and cant be rectified so ...

Comment: `exp[i]` is a `char`, but `push` expects a `string`.

Comment: thanks @ cigien i was not thought of it

Comment: @Tamizhselvan the compiler should warn you

Answer (score 0):

`push(st, std::to_string(exp[i]));` should fix your problem!